# tabBarItem's title didn't appear

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

i am using a tab bar in a view controller  and in "viewDidLoad" method i declare it:

```
    normalView =[[NormalViewController alloc] initWithSigne:[[normalAstro objectAtIndex:signIndex]objectForKey :@"name"] andDescription:[[normalAstro objectAtIndex:signIndex]objectForKey :@"description"]] ;

[controllers addObject:normalView];
chineseIndex=[self searchChineseIndex];
chineseView =[[ChineseViewController alloc] initWithSigne:[[chineseAstro objectAtIndex:chineseIndex]objectForKey :@"name"] andDescription:[[chineseAstro objectAtIndex:chineseIndex]objectForKey :@"description"]] ;


[controllers addObject:chineseView];

tabBar = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tabBar.viewControllers=controllers;

[self.view addSubview:tabBar.view ];
```

and the viewControllers that are putted in the tabBar i write this to init them:

```
[self.tabBarItem setTitle:@"signe astral" ] ;
```

the problem that the title of the tabBarItem didn't appear for me ,so my question where is my mistake in all of this?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
self.title = @"signe astral";
```

to set the title of the UIViewController, not on `self.tabBarItem`.

Comment: I found the opposite - when I tried setting the controller title, it would just end up blank, but when I set the `tabBarItem` title, then it'd work

Comment: Okay, so I did some more investigation. When both self.title and self.tabBarItem.title are set then no title displays. Both of these properties can be set via interface builder, which makes things more confusing

Comment: Thanks for the downvote. It was an answer to Dingua a year ago. If you need help you should post your code and not downvote a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just you have to decalre in,

```
   self.title = @"signe astral";
```

If you want title and images in your tab bar. So you have to use this code.

```
     UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sss.png"];

     self.tabBar = [[[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"signe astral" image:img tag:1] autorelease];
```

Thanks.